# Is it possible to filter SonarQube coverage treemap?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, dashboard

I find the SonarQube code coverage treemap/heatmap less useful because of 2 things:

1. It's limited to 30 repositories
2. We have a million-line code monolith that obscures the other, tiny repositories

So, I'd like to be able to exclude a repository from the view, and remove the limitation of 30 repositories - no luck finding this in the documentation or online. Does anyone know the answer on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Measure Filter as Treemap widget.

First you'll need to create, save, and share a Measure Filter that includes your target projects.

Then add a Measure Filter as Treemap widget to your dashboard and configure it to show your saved filter.